# Recyclerview heavy data loading

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which needs to show tags in each of its item-views. But the thing is tags can be as many as 100. So for each tag, a `TextView` will be created. So for one item a loop will run for the size of tags and adds `TextView`. By doing this `RecyclerView` lags. Is there any way to create those views in a separate thread?

Comment: Show more information, include the code, please.

Comment: Sounds like you should reconsider the UI. 100 Text views in a grid cell will not be legible.